# Convert a string to Dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, dictionary

I have a dataframe with several columns which i obtain from csv, which in some columns it has another dictionary. I then proceed to do the following

```
df = df.set_index('case_id')
dictionary = df.to_dict('index')
list = list(dictionary.keys())
df = df.reset_index()
```

All perfect to here, I obtain the dictionary as expected with the index as it's key.
Now the problem starts here, In some column "b" I have another dictionary which for some reason is type string.

When i do `dictionary[key]['b']` I expect to recieve a dictionary with the following format

```
'{0: [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 13, 41, 37), 1162.0], 1: [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 14, 0, 59), 347.0], 2: [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 14, 6, 46), 1719.0], 3: [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 14, 35, 25), 14.0], ... }'
```

However when I do `type(dictionary[key]['b'])` it is referenced as `<class 'str'>`, how can I transform this as to a dictionary?

Comment: Hi Jose - would you take a moment to please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples ? and [edit] your Q accordingly?

Comment: How did this string get into the dataframe in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval()`

```
eval(dictionary[key]['b'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked.

Comment: What is populating the dataframe? Be *very* careful with what you pass to `eval`, as it will execute an arbitrary Python expression, whether it was something you intended to execute or not.